# "error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context" when trying to send a udp packet in my python script

Tags: python-2.7

so I am getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Demo Stand\test srcipts\attack_PLC.py", line 97, in <module>
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

and here is my code:

```
import sys
import time
import socket


ans = True
ans1 = True
output01 = "" 
UDP_IP = str(output01)##if this is set to something like this "192.168.56.1" instead of output01 it works.
TankID = 0
UDP_PORT = int(TankID)
MESSAGE = "pump on"
MESSAGE2 = "fire"
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

   while ans:

        output01 = raw_input("Enter target IP Address:")

        TankID = raw_input("Enter target ID:")
        TankID = TankID.strip(' \t\n\r')
        UDP_PORT = int(TankID)

        if output01 == output01 :
                print "Target Aquired"
                break
while ans1:
        output02 = raw_input("Environment Acquired....Press 'Y' to execute: ")
        if output02 == 'y':
                print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
                print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
                sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
                time.sleep(5)
                sock.sendto(MESSAGE2, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
                break
```

I don't know why it is not just sending the packet. when i set the UDP_IP variable to any ip address as something like "192.168.56.1" it runs fine, but when I store it from the raw input it gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to the fact that you are not escaping the carriage return (\n or \r\n) from the raw_input:
output01 = output01.strip(' \t\n\r')
might do the trick.

You should consider checking Scapy for that kind of stuff, though.